# How to generate cumulative concatenation in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Input for spark is below:

| Col_1 | Col_2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 35/310320 |
| 1 | 1 | 35/5 |
| 1 | 1 | 180/-310350 |
| 17 | 1 | 0/1000 |
| 17 | 17 | 0/-1000 |
| 17 | 17 | 74/314322 |
| 17 | 17 | 74/5 |
| 17 | 17 | 185/-3142 |

I want to generate the below Output using spark SQL:

| Output |
| --- |
| 35/310320 |
| 35/310320/35/5 |
| 35/310320/35/5/180/-310350 |
| 0/1000 |
| 0/1000/0/-1000 |
| 0/1000/0/-1000/74/314322 |
| 0/1000/0/-1000/74/314322/74/5 |
| 0/1000/0/-1000/74/314322/74/5/185/-3142 |

Conditions & Procedure: If `col_1` and `col_2` values are not the same then consider the current amount value for the new Output column but both are the same then concatenate the previous all amount value by `/`.

i.e. 17 from `col_1` where `col_1` & `col_2` value are different so consider current amount `0/1000`. Next step both column values is the same so the value is `0/1000/0/-1000` and so on. Need to create this logic for dynamic data in spark SQL or Spark Scala.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat_ws` on a list of amount obtained from `collect_list` over an appropriate window:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "output", 
    concat_ws(
        "/", 
        collect_list("amount").over(
            Window.partitionBy("col_1")
                  .orderBy("col_2")
                  .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
        )
    )
)
```